# Get logged in User info for Non Admin users in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I am trying to retrieve data of logged-in users that are not admins. I am at the moment able to get usernames but nothing else is possible at the moment if they have not made any posts.

This is making a custom url endpoint to get some userinfo. Unfortunately the wp-json/wp/v2 endpoint does not help a lot at the moment.

The wp_get_current_user method does not work and the get current_user_id method also display 0

```
public function get_items( $request ) {
        require_once('wp-load.php');
        $current_user = "";    

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        //ADD THESE LINES
                
                $cookie = $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE];
                if ( !empty($cookie)) {
                    $cookie_elements = explode('|', $cookie);
                    $current_user = $cookie_elements[0];
                }
                // if(function_exists('wp_get_current_user'))
                // {
                //     $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                //     $user_login = $current_user->$user_login;
                // }
        //ABOVE HERE
        
                $items = [
                        'foo' => 'bar',
                        'wpuser' => $current_user,
                        'moreuser' => $user_id
                ];
        
                $response = rest_ensure_response( $items );
        
                return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want get all currently logged in users which are not admins.

First we need to determine when our Wordpress users last logged in and out, to gather current logged in users. We can do this by creating `last_activity_time` user meta field with the relevant timestamp upon user logging in and out...

```php
// wp_login action function
function update_last_activity_time($user_login) {
    
    // get the current user id
    $user_id = get_user_by('login', $user_login)->ID;

    // update the 'last_activity_time' user meta field with the current timestamp
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_activity_time', current_time('timestamp'));

}

// wp_login action function call
add_action('wp_login', 'update_last_activity_time');

// wp_logout action function
function update_last_logout_time() {

    // get the current user id
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // update the 'last_activity_time' user meta field with the current timestamp
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_activity_time', current_time('timestamp'));

}

// wp_logout action function call
add_action('wp_logout', 'update_last_logout_time');
```

So now every time any user logs in or out it stores a timestamp on current users meta field `last_activity_time`.

Then to get current non admin users which have logged in within the last 30 minutes, you can do something like this...

```php
// get current logged in non admin users
function get_online_users() {

    // set empty users array
    $online_users = [];

    // get the current timestamp
    $current_time = current_time('timestamp');

    // set 30 min interval for considering users as online
    $online_interval = 30 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS;

    // wp user query args
    $args = [
        'meta_key' => 'last_activity_time',
        'meta_value' => $current_time - $online_interval,
        'meta_compare' => '>',
        'fields' => 'all',
        'exclude' => [1], // exclude admins by user role id
    ];

    // get the online users via wp user query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

    // wp user query results
    $users = $user_query->get_results();

    // check if any users are found
    if (!empty($users)) {

        // each user as user object
        foreach ($users as $user) {

            // add the user id to the online_users array
            $online_users[] = $user->ID;

        }

    }

    // return user id's online in the last 30 mins
    return $online_users;

}
```

Use like this to return non admin user id's...

```php
var_dump(get_online_users());
```